# How can I write cross-platform c++ programs on my mac?

Tags: c++, gcc, portability

My university professor has given a requirement for us in his c++ class: We must write our programs using the gnu C++ compiler (GCC).  I understand that after installing xcode, I get an apple version of gcc.  However, this is not fully cross compatible as I understand.  So I have tried to install the gnu gcc compiler by using mac ports, but I have been unsuccessful.  After doing:

```
port install gcc47
```

When I go to the terminal and run:

```
gcc47 -v
```

I get "command not found"
When I run:

```
gcc -v
```

I get:

```
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
```

Showing that I am still using apple's version.  The part I am not understanding is:

1. How do I install gcc (the gnu version, not apple's version)
2. How do I use it with an ide, such as eclipse?

Comment: Apple's version of GCC should be compatible with other versions of GCC. You will be able to compile the same source code to run on any platform that has any C++ compiler, provided you only use functions in the C++ standard library. Note that there are sometimes inconsistencies - code that'll work in one compiler and not another, but Apple's GCC isn't special in that regard.

Comment: Sounds like you did the right thing when installing the new compiler, did you get any error messages when you ran the port install gcc47? If not, try /opt/local/bin/gcc47. Otherwise I'd just use XCode's gcc until I found a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The version of GCC you use (Apple or gnu native) should be irrelevant for you to proceed.

Writing portable C++ has nothing to do with the compiler--outside of ensuring your compiler does it's best to adhere to the C++ standard. **Luckily enough, GCC is one of the best C++ compilers out there.**

You're not looking to do cross-platform C++ per-se, because true portable C++ is somewhat of a pain to write given the various state of C++ compilers for various systems (for example the CC on VAX/VMS doesn't support templates...). I suspect what you want to do is ensure the code you write on your mac, can be compiled by your prof. As long as GCC can handle it on your mac, it should be fine.

So to your specific questions:

Your first question is unnecessary, as you can use apple's supplied g++ to compile your code.

For your second question, I would highly recommend against using an IDE while trying to learn. IDE's offer some really great time saving features, but they hide some important aspects, that I believe are worth struggling with early in your learning process, and which will help strengthen your C++ skills. And while things have certainly have gotten better, some IDE's were notorious for creating non-portable C++ (ie using `void main()`).

If you are still set on using Eclipse, or XCode, since it doesn't matter which GCC installation you use, the default setup should work just fine.

Comment: I am not wanting to compile a binary that will run across platforms, I understand that.  I also understand your opinion about IDE's.  However, the main issue that I am trying to avoid is having a different environment than my professor.  He compiles using the gnu gcc.  And if I compile using anything else, then I could potentially run into some issues, when he tries to compile my code on his platform.  This is the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Understandable. Unless you are doing something very edge-case, you should be fine with the default gcc compiler that comes installed on your mac.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into troubles installing `gcc47` via ports in the past, but `gcc46` went as expected. You may also want to install `gcc_select`.

From there, you can use `gcc_select`, or specify the path explicitly in Eclipse's toolchain editor.

Other notes:

- If you don't need C++11 features, then Apple's GCC 4.2.1 should work fine. Perhaps you can detail why you can't use it. Basically, Apple's added some extensions to the toolchain in some cases (marked APPLE_ONLY), and you have good control of what options are enabled/disabled.
- Recent versions of Clang which ship with Xcode handle C++ well (including some support for C++11). There are some advanced things in GCC that I miss when using Clang, but Clang's current C++ support is really quite good.